# How to fix the changing height of <td > in table?

Tags: html, css

I am fetching data from the database. While displaying the height of the table get changing. I want to fix it. That means it must not change  height according to the database content.The height and width of the cell must be fixed.In this case width is fixed.
**But I am not getting how to fix height and it must not change it's height but it can change it's width.**

```html
 <?php
    include("C:\wamp64\www\DashBoard\Config2.php");
    echo '<DOCTYPE html>
            <head>
              </head>
                <section>
                  <body>';
                  function id($db,$p){
                    echo'<div class="tbl-header">
                      <table style="float: left; width:50% table-layout:fixed; height:50% padding:0px;" border="1" cellpadding="7"  >
                        <thead>
                           <tr>
                              <th colspan=5 style="width:15%">Testcase id</th>
                              <th colspan=5 style="width:70%">Testcase </th>

                           </tr>   
                        </thead>
                     </div>
            <div class="tbl-content"> 
              <tbody>';
                  $sql="select prefix, tc_id, tc_description from (select prefix ,tc_id ,SUBSTRING(tc_summary,4,25) as tc_description from executions1 join project_table on project_id=pro_id where pro_id=$p) as t;";  
                  $query=mysqli_query($db,$sql);
                   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
                     echo '<tr>
                      <td colspan=5 style="width:15%">'.$row['prefix'].'-'.$row['tc_id'].'</td>
                      <td colspan=5 style="width:70%">'.$row['tc_description'].'</td>
                      </tr>';
                   }
              echo'</tbody>
             </div>
           </table>';
          }//id method ends
     echo'</body>
      </section> 
    </html>';
     $pro="select  count(project_name)from project_table;";
     $res=mysqli_query($db,$pro);
     $row=mysqli_fetch_array($res);
     $cntp=$row['count(project_name)'];

          for($p=1;$p<=$cntp;$p++){
                //displaying project id's
                id($db,$p);}
    ?>
```

Can anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: Did you try using CSS to fix the height? You could apply a `height` attribute to the `tr` or `td` I would think. CSS would be best. Alternatively (and less desirable) did you try adding `height` to your `style` attribute? *E.g.*, `style="width: 15%; height: 20px"` or something like that?

Comment: Height on the TD should definitely work (assuming it's taller than the content that gets populated).

Comment: But here I am fetching data from database. Therefore the of <td>is changing accroding to the database content weight. But To make it fix.

Comment: You could set the `height` to a fix absolute size (like 20px or whatever) and also set overflow to either allow inner-scroll or just hide the overflow content of the `<td>` by `overflow: auto;` or `overflow: hidden`. This way the height of the the `<td>` element will remain fixed and the content won't overflow...